# How can I prevent other text from shifting on hover with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a category selector in my React app, and the category labels are displayed with flexbox so that they can be spaced evenly and horizontally. I've applied some styling changes to the hovered text to make the font weight heavier, but doing so has caused the labels surrounding the hovered one to shift. Is there a way I can fix this so that hovering doesnt cause anything to move, but instead just change the font weight?

Here's my CSS:

```
.skills-category-selector {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.category-label {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.category-label:hover {
    font-weight: 800;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You would have to make the width of your labels _not_ dependent on their text content to begin with - which is probably not what you want. Or you could use a bit of trickery - make the actual text content invisible/transparent on hover (but have it still be there, so that it can determine the dimensions of the label) - and then duplicate the text in a pseudo element, that you position absolute above the label, so that when its width changes, that doesn't affect the label itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-shadow` to increase text boldness instead

```css
.skills-category-selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.category-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.category-label:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-category-selector">
  <span class="category-label">Category 1</span>
  <span class="category-label">Category 2</span>
  <span class="category-label">Category 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution can help you, you need to use pseudo-elements https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/ or just assign a specific width on every .category-label

```css
.skills-category-selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.category-label{
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.category-label:hover {
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
   <div class="skills-category-selector">
     <span class="category-label">Category 1</span>
     <span class="category-label">Category 2</span>
     <span class="category-label">Category 3</span>
     <span class="category-label">Category 3</span>
   </div>
```